# Can we make a call to server through jquery ajax

Tags: jquery

I am trying to hit the server from the local host but it is not to hitting it.
It not going to hit the url.  How can I resolve it?  Up to else block I put alert it is going then it is not hitting the server through url.  If both the username and password are entered it has to go the server and execute the sql query and get back the result to the same page. I am doing it from an html page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"http://google.com",//here I am getting the problem
        data:dataString,
        success:function(data) {
            alert('success');
        },error :function(data) {
        alert('Error has Occured');
        }
    });
    }
    return false;
</script>
```

i am doing it for login page.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps google isn't letting you POST to their homepage?  Look at the response in the Network tab of Developer Tools (F12 in Chrome).

Comment: It won't work because of cross-origin restrictions. In fact, that's exactly what the console says: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://google.com/. Origin http://stackoverflow.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. `